# Is there a way to upgrade bitcoin daemon to version 25?

Tags: bitcoin, bitcoind

I downloaded bitcoin core 25 from bitcoincore.org, but the only instructions I could find relating to the installation of the bitcoin daemon was on bitcoin.org (which seems to only offer up to bitcoin 22).

The instructions on bitcoin.org are as follows:

> The Bitcoin Core daemon (bitcoind) is not included in the .dmg file
> you may have downloaded to install Bitcoin-QT. Bitcoind, along with
> its support binaries, is instead included in the OS X .tar.gz file
> listed on the official Bitcoin Core download page. To download this
> file using Terminal, execute the following command:
>
> curl -O
> https://bitcoin.org/bin/bitcoin-core-22.0/bitcoin-22.0-osx64.tar.gz

Now when I use the "bitcoind -version" comman in terminal, it says

Bitcoin Core version v22.0.0

However this is weird because when I open bitcoin core, the orange bitcoin icon app, and click "about" it says it is bitcoin core 25.

Any idea how I can get the daemon to match the bitcoin core?